# Правка реестра через .bat

Tags: bat, реестр

Есть .reg файл:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"AutoAdminLogon"=dword:00000001

"DefaultDomainName"="Domain1"

"DefaultUserName"="User1"
```

Нужно написать батник, чтобы открывалось окно, где пользователь будет вводить имя учетной записи в домене.
Затем батник будет подставлять введенное имя учетной записи в реестр вместо `User1:`
`"DefaultUserName"="User1"`.

**Обновление**

Зачем столько мороки?

Есть уже рабочий рег файл, который делает то, что должен делать. Нужно написать батник, благодаря которому, при ручном методе ввода параметра вносятся изменения либо в этот рег файл, либо сразу же в реестр.

Как это должно выглядеть?

Двойной клик мышкой на фалй .bat. Открывается черное окно, в котором написано:

> "Введите имя учетной записи"

Вводишь имя учетки, нажимаешь Enter. Батник закидывает введенные данные в рег файл либо сразу же в реестр.

Как написать такой батник? Или при помощи .bat нельзя вводить какие-либо значения переменные и т.п.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Убивать старый рег-файл;
2. Создавать эхами новый;
3. запускать на выполнение (или делать Reg Import).

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set /p usrname="Username: "
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d Domain1 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d %usrname% /f
```

Запускаем батник от имени администратора, на запрос `Username:` вводим имя пользователя, которого надо добавить, нажимаем `Enter`. Всё.